# What is the name given to the solution to the equation $cU = Y U Y$ for a given symmetric, positive definite, real-valued matrix $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, similarity

Overarching question is: What is the name given to the solution to the equation $cU = Y U Y$ for a given symmetric, positive definite, real-valued matrix $Y$? And what procedure is used to solve this efficiently? (though I can probably find the answer to the second from the first)

The motivation for this problem is the following similarity task: I have $n$ entities each with a set of $m$ features, represented in an $m \times n$ real-valued matrix $X$; in my case $n >> m$. I want an $n \times n$ entity similarity matrix (call it $U$), according to the entities' features. Specifically, entities $i$ and $j$ are similar (so $u_{ij}$ is high) if they have similar features; and conversely, features $k$ and $l$ are similar if they are expressed by similar entities. In order to do this, we'll also need to define the $m \times m$ feature similarity matrix $W$.

This formulation gives me:
$c_1 u_{ij} = \sum_{k,l} x_{ik} x_{jl} w_{kl}$, for some constant of proportionality $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$

or equivalently: $c_1U = X^T W X$

and similarly:
$c_2 W = X U X^T$

So $c$ and $U$ that solves (or best approximates) the following equation should be my entity similarity matrix:
$cU = (X^TX) U (X^TX)$ or $cU = YUY$ for positive definite $Y$

And the solution to the following is my feature similarity matrix:
$cW = (XX^T) W (XX^T)$

That said, I'm not wedded to this formulation: If there are more standard ways of thinking about similarity of entities and features (even if it's not exactly the problem formulation I have) that results in an easier linear algebra problem, I'll happily switch over! I imagine someone's already solved both the linear algebra question I'm posing, and also the broader question of this sort of similarity decomposition, but I'm not able to find the right search terms to read about what's already been done. I'd be curious to learn what this class of problems and the corresponding amily of algorithms to solve them are called.

Hence I'm asking:

1. What is the name given to the solution to the equation $cU = Y U Y$ for a given symmetric, positive definite, real-valued matrix $Y$?
2. What is the problem of simultaneously identifying entity and feature similarity called in the literature? And/or what are the simplest or most common approaches to solving this problem?

Comment: ad 1)  I don’t know if this has a special name but it is just the eigenvalue problem for the linear mapping $U \to YUY$.  By a standard result of linear algebra you can assume that $Y$ is a diagonal matrix with positive elements and then it can be solved by hand (may I suggest that you start with the $2\times 2$ version to see what is going on).

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I'll definitely look into doing it that way; for me, $X$ is sparse but has like 30 million rows so I would want to ensure an efficient solution to the eigenvalue problem.Also, I remembered that recommender systems tend to use similar similarity formulations; model-based collaborative filtering factorizes $X$ and then treats the dot product of the rows of the entity-factor matrix as the similarity scores. posting in case anyone else has the same question and/or if this sparks any other suggestions: towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-recommender-systems-6c66cf15ada